# Processing ebXML - InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, ebxml

I am trying to parse ebXML message using a Proprietary integration engine based on Java in a Healthcare setting. I am getting this error

InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message -appreciate  feedback

I have the following top section

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
SOAP-ENV:Header<wsa:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">urn:ihe:iti:2007:RegistryStoredQueryResponse</wsa:Action>wsa:MessageIDurn:uuid:612A6A6C-3FSF-11EB-1111-005056AB1983</wsa:MessageID>wsa:RelatesTo9871d7b2-a5a7-41b2-2193-25a29f36b44d</wsa:RelatesTo>wsa:Tohttp://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
SOAP-ENV:Body<query:AdhocQueryResponse xmlns:query="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ResponseStatusType:Success">
<rim:RegistryObjectList xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0">
<rim:ExtrinsicObject id="urn:uuid:d5b1e2e0-08ec-11eb-869b-d09466039146" lid="urn:uuid:d5bfg2e0-08ec-11eb-869b-d09463439146" mimeType="text/xml" objectType="urn:uuid:7e45678-054d-47f2-a032-9b2a5b5186c1" status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Approved">
<rim:Slot name="creationTime">

Comment: The xml is not valid.  Use an online xml checker and you will see the errors. The code that generated the xml is bad of the xml got corrupted.

Comment: I have only posted the SOAP Envelope and header.  Appreciate any  some clues on SOAP envelope /header

Comment: Use an online check : https://www.xmlvalidation.com/